# Google Sheets - filter list excluding values from other list

Tags: list, google-sheets, filter

I have a big sheet `raw_data` which is automatically populated by a script every 5 minutes. As such I cannot add new columns with formulas but have to solve problems in single formulas.

The challenge:

I need to pull out a list of unique values from a column `O`. At the same time, I need to filter out a certain set of values in range `A55:A`

I have this formula to pull out the unique values:
`=SORT(UNIQUE(raw_data!O2:O))`

I tried playing with match, but how do I "inverse" the result from the `match` as I'm actually looking to 
*exclude* rather than *include*:
`=SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(raw_data!O2:O,IFERROR((Match(raw_data!O2:O,A75:A200,0))))))`

I tried adding a `NOT()` around the `Match()` but that then gave me a no results error.

Anyone?

Comment: I'd love to use Google Query for this, but it doesn't seem the SQL ```NOT IN()``` is supported unfortunately..  Wish Google Query was more extensive

Comment: Can you show with the image -> before and after

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using NOT use [ISNA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093293?hl=en)

The above because [MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en) returns `#N/A` when there is no match.

Related

- [Return FALSE for #N/A in if match statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38726560/1595451)
- [Filter out all of user's entries if one of them was selected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45737994/1595451)